# How to implement Kendo Gantt chart Jquery in react

Tags: kendo-ui, gantt-chart, kendo-gantt

I wanted to implement kendo gantt chart in react but in react library they dont have full feature like drag the scheduler time but in jquery they have that functionality and other things. so i wanted to implement jquery gantt chart in react
Jquery Gantt chart link [https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/gantt/index](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
can anyone share codesandox

Jquery Gantt chart link[ https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/gantt/index](